# JavaScript Object wont get to PHP Controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to get a javascript Objecto to my php controller, but it arrives empty.

This is the object.[image]

This is how it arrives (empty)
[image]
This is my ajax.
[image]

```
var SendMovs = {                              
     Movimentos: CacheQL.Movimentos              
 };                                             

    console.log(SendMovs);
    var Link = $('#LINK').val() + '/?action=ajax_saveroyalty';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: Link, 
        dataType : 'text',
        data: SendMovs,
        success: function(server_response)
        {

        $('.ibox-content').append(server_response);
```

If i send

```
CacheQL.Movimentos.CodProduto
```

I get the object in the controller, but i need it in .Movimentos

Ive tried the JSON.stringify(Var) already...

Answer (score 0):

Use  dataType : 'application/json', instead of  dataType : 'text'.

Comment: Try with this one -   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: Link, 
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: "json",
       data: JSON.stringify(SendMovs),
       success: function(server_response){
            $('.ibox-content').append(server_response);
       },
       error: function(response) {
           console.log(response);
       }
    });

Comment: Already did that, and did it again but still empty in the controller and no erros in console. Can't figure out why.